# Undoing A Sitecore Publish

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Aside from investing in TDS or restoring the SQL database, is it possible to undo/rollback a Sitecore publish if someone publishes something that shouldn't have been?

I am using Sitecore 8.

Answer (score 5):

If you know what the items are that were published, you could set the version that should not have been published to un-publishable and re-publish the item. That would set it back to the previous version.

Comment: What if you weren't sure what had been published -- or if a large number had been published?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the Sitecore logs for the items that have been published and then republish the versions intended while setting the unwanted versions unpublishable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting you can activate in the config that logs every item thats been published:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.UpdateStatistics, Sitecore.Kernel" runIfAborted="true">
    <traceToLog>false</traceToLog>
</processor>
```

Beware it will add lots of information to the logs.

If you need to check back in time without this setting as **true** things get a bit harder. You could interrogate the history tables and eventqueue tables as these contain all the items that have changed and therefore contribute towards smart publishes. The logs should give you a view of what type of publishes have been run: smart vs incremental vs republish, and where in the tree they were kicked off.

Unfortunately there isn't the concept of a transaction over a publish, like Richard mentioned you'd need to replay items back over the top, or get a db restored.